# Is possible to use the solution template in exams2nops?

Tags: r, r-exams

When I try to generate the exams' solution with the `exams2nops(...template="solution"...)` I get the following error message:

```
Error in exams2pdf(file, n = n, nsamp = nsamp, dir = dir, name = name,  : 
  formal argument "template" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

How can I produce an exams' solution with the `exams2nops`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in one go, you need two runs after setting the same seed, e.g.,

```
set.seed(1)
exams2nops(my_exam)
set.seed(1)
exams2pdf(my_exam, template = "my_solution.tex")
```

You can use the `solution.tex` provided within the package as a starting point for `my_solution.tex`. But you may want to translate it to your natural language, use the name of your university, possibly insert a logo, add your actual exam name, possibly some into text etc. In `exams2pdf()` you need to add these things in the template LaTeX file directly.

Comment: The exam was created some day ago... Do I have to create a "my_solution.tex"?

Comment: Have you kept the seed? I would always recommend to do that. // As for "my_solution.tex": I would assume that you want to have it in pt (rather than en) with your actual university and exam name etc. // When I wrote exams2pdf() I assumed that everybody would want to tweak their own LaTeX master template anyway - as opposed to inserting certain pieces of information into a flexible template. That's why exam.tex and solution.tex are really just demo files and not for use in production.

Comment: I did not keep the seed. But the right answer stills the same, the order will be different (due to exshuffle) but that's not a big issue. I understand, I will use the template `exams/tex` folder and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

won't the template="solution" not work in the exams2pdf? Also, can we do something like:

`usepackage = "pdfpages", intro = intro2,...` ?